# known contained polygons on geopandas return everything False for "contain" and "within" when dissolving one layer

Tags: geopandas, spatial-join, overlay, within

I have two geodataframes:
gdf1= 1000 polygons
gdf2= 26 polygons that are bounding box of 26 polygons from gdf1.
[image: Demonstration of the polygons (pink) and the bounding boxes (red)]

I would like to get the all the polygons from gdf1 that **are not** within gdf2.

I decided to start with finding which polygons are within gdf2, and then to get all the other.
I wanted to do something similar to this sql expression:

```
MbrContains("gdf2"."geometry","gdf1"."geometry")
```

Hence I have tried this expression in geopandas:

```
test = gdf1[gdf2.contains(gdf)]
```

But this returned only False, even though I know they are contained.
Then , [after reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385782/make-a-union-of-polygons-in-geopandas-or-shapely-into-a-single-geometry) , I tried to dissolve all the polygon on gdf2 into one multipolygon and then to use contain, as following :

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

gdf2['new_column'] = 0
gdf2 = gdf2.dissolve(by='new_column')


gdf1['check']=gdf2.contains(gdf1)
gdf1['check']=gdf1.within(gdf2)
```

but both return False for everything.

other things I did:

- made sure the projections are the same (using set_crs)

I know I can also use spatial join for this, but I would like to understand why contains/within doesn't work in this case.

---

Based on @Ian’s answer, I have tried the following:

```
#make sure again that gdf2 is one line after dissolve:
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

gdf2['new_column'] = 0
gdf2 = gdf2.dissolve(by='new_column')
>>>

                                        geometry    id
new_column      
0   MULTIPOLYGON (((-104.16217 45.77291, -104.12332...  0


#iterate through rows:
checks=[]
for index, row in gdf1.iterrows():
    # Access the geometry of the current row
    tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf1.iloc[index,:]).T

    checks.append(gdf2.contains(tmp))

#print checks:
>>>[new_column
 0    False
 dtype: bool,
 0    False
 1    False
 dtype: bool,
 0    False
 2    False
 dtype: bool,
 0    False
 3    False
 dtype: bool,
 0    False
 4    False
```

I wasn't scpecting this results, I thought I would get "True" or False" , and not per point. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking (in effect) if any one polygon contains all of the other polygons or not.

You need to extract a single multi-polygon by dissolving all the polygons of your bounding box layer and then for each row of the 2nd collection check if it is contained in that multi-polygon.

Comment: I have dissolved the bounding boxes  to one multipolygon. But it surprised me that I still need to iterate through polygon to check that.

Comment: can you check that `gdf2` only has one row?

Comment: I have edited the question with this information